# How to implement cascade select fields in ODK Aggregate XLSForm with data coming from csv files

Tags: odk, xlsform

I a working with odk aggregate. I need to create a form with the following requirements:
In my form I have departments, provinces and districts (spanish 'departamento', 'provincia', 'distrito'). A department has many provinces, and a province has many districts.
The lists of provinces and districts is coming from csv files 'provinces.csv' and 'districts.csv'. The choices for departments is defined 'departamento_choices' in the choices tab.
I want to implement a cascade selection. First select the Department, then select the Province and last select the district.
I implemented a solution but when I try to upload the form to odk aggregate it returns an error.
It said that the requirements is syntactically incorrect
[image: ODK showing error]

This is what i have done so far
This is form definition:
[image: Form definition]

This is the departamento_choices
[image: Choices department]

This is the provinces.csv
[image: Provinces]

This is the districts.csv
[image: Districts list]

How can I solve the problem? Is there any way to get a more descriptive error?